# Styling Listview Item like selected Metro Tile

Tags: android, android-activity

![I would like to create listview item style as below image.

Any suggestions?
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lE7eo.jpg)

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/lE7eo.jpg

Comment: check this http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/10/android-custom-listview-images-text-example.html

Comment: I am new to StackOverflow so not gained enough points to put Image here is the link what i actually want to achiev.  http://i.stack.imgur.com/lE7eo.jpg

Answer (score 0):

you have to set a Boolean flag in your data structure object , whenever some item is selected make it true and implement the style to your listview item, to add style you can make changes or set style using Boolean variable.

Comment: Thanks for your time to answer my question but my issue is how to Style Listview Item Like Windows 8 Metro Tile selected style Link of image what i actually want to achieve is http://i.stack.imgur.com/lE7eo.jpg

Comment: you can make a xml file in drawable and you can replace image on different state like on-selected , onfoucs and default . in this selected item you can set background image on on selected state.

Comment: Thanks again but i am empty handed buddy.. I know to create xml with Shapes and use diffrent background on diffrent state like selected pressed, but trazady is i am not able to generate xml which look like it

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.

i created a class with My Background.java and created the desired layout by adding rectangle and path using points on a canvas.
And programmatically set the background of listview to this class.